# How to start gVim maximized?

Tags: vim, gvim, cross-platform

How to make gVim automatically maximize it's window when I open it? And a cross-plataform solution, I'm trying to use the same configs in a Linux and Windows machine...

I've tried the hack `:set lines=999 columns=999`, it almost works, but the window is not maximized, just resized and I lose some rows/columns.

Comment: That's the most portable way I know. Could you elaborate on the "but the window is not maximized, just resized and I lose some rows/columns". Maximization is afaik, resizing till the edges. And I don't think I ever lost a row/col in that way.

Comment: @Idigas: correct, maximization is just "resize till it fills up available space (not covering toolbars etc)", in terms of wm-speak :)

Comment: Setting the hack above doesn't resize till the edges. I'm starting to think the better approach is going to add an if in my vimrc: if it'd windows, call a config, else, call other config.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way if you're concerned about cross-platform compatibility is `set lines=999 columns=999`. I've found it in [Vim's Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size), and despite it's not perfect, it's a best solution if you need to work on different operating systems.

Comment: Can you combine this with au GUIEnter * simalt ~x   ??

Comment: Yes, creating a condition in your vimrc to know if it's windows or Linux. Since I'm mainly using Linux, I'm going to add this config later.

Comment: This approach does not work for me under GNOME 3. When the window was already non-maximized, this will slow down Vim for a little while (does not happen when I maximize using the window manager), and it will leave a little edge above the window uncovered, because my screen height is not a perfect multiple of line height. When the window was vertically (but not horizontally) maximized by dragging the window to the left or right of the screen, this will have no effect.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio For these situations (multiple desktop environments in Linux), I am seriously thinking about using [devilspie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/). It's a third-party solution, I know, but it may work. I've used it in some other applications I wanted to be open maximized.

Comment: This also causes the window to become huge if you un-maximize it.

Answer (score 31):

From the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size):

```
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

That'll work on Windows; I'm not sure what key combinations you'd need on Gnome/KDE.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: It also depends on the OS language sadly. For French Windows versions, it becomes `au GUIEnter * simalt ~n`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite, to un-maximize? Seems like `:simalt ~x` only works one way on Windows7x64 ENG.

Comment: `~x` comes from keyboard shortcut for menu option. Check the shortcut for desire option and try it. Maybe it's `R`estore?

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik Thanks, you're right. I didn't realize that `simalt` meant 'simulate the alt keypress'. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

### On GNU/Linux

On GNU/Linux, the easiest way is to invoke `gvim` with the `-geometry` option. For example:

```
gvim -geometry 1336x744
```

This is obviously not handy if you would like to reuse the same start command on different machines.

Here is what I am using now on several machines with different screen dimensions without any issues.
Just add it somewhere high up in your `.vimrc`.

```
if has("gui_running")
  " GUI is running or is about to start.
  " Maximize gvim window (for an alternative on Windows, see simalt below).
  set lines=999 columns=999
else
  " This is console Vim.
  if exists("+lines")
    set lines=50
  endif
  if exists("+columns")
    set columns=100
  endif
endif
```

Source:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size

Comment: For linux this is probably the best option. in .zshrc do  alias v="gvim -geometry 1366x768" and you're set for good.

Answer (score 6):

Trick with:

```
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

depends on Windows language.

For my Polish version works:

au GUIEnter * simalt ~s

Where `s` comes from `Mak_s_ymalizuj`.

So if `~x` doesn't work press `ALT+SPACE` to open Window menu and check shortcut for *Ma_x_imize Window* menu option.

Comment: And ~n for french ("Agra&ndir")

Comment: And ~m for Norwegian

Answer (score 4):

You can use [maximize.dll](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1302) plugin for fullscreen veiw on Vim (if you are using Windows). Just copy maximize.dll into `vimdirectory/plugin` folder.

Answer (score 3):

For me, `:simalt ~x` did the trick. (Windows 7, English.)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** for linux users, I've found much better solution that really does maximize the window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448179/how-to-maximize-vims-windows-on-startup-with-vimrc

The only dependency is `wmctrl`, but it worths installing.

So, for windows I use [maximize.dll](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1302) plugin (as already mentioned by @fatihturan), and for linux I use `wmctrl`. Great!

(but I really can't understand why in 2014 gvim doesn't have this feature out-of-the-box)

---

Old answer:

---

For me, plain hack `:set lines=999 columns=999` works badly on my Linux Mint MATE with two monitors. I have usually gvim opened on the secondary monitor, there're no taskbar, so, Vim should occupy the whole screen. But if I do `:set lines=999 columns=999`, gvim shrinks these values to the size of **primary** monitor, therefore, there are a small area below gvim window unused. It's better if I set real lines/columns count: just maximize your window "by hand" and type `:set lines?` and `:set columns?` , to get needed values. Since I use two monitors, I also need to specify window position, so, type `:winpos` to get current window position.

And secondary, it's better not just put these settings to the `.vimrc`, but execute them when gui is loaded.

So, final recipe:

1) maximize your gvim by hand and type three commands to get actual values: `:winpos` ,  `:set lines?` and `:set columns?` .

2) add this to `.vimrc` :

```
function Maximize()

   " put your actual values below
   winpos 0 0
   set lines=78
   set columns=237

endfunction

autocmd GUIEnter * call Maximize()
```

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you can dinamically get the lines and columns values in vimscript, so this config will work in all devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you want vim to achieve full screen in Windows thoroughly (like in the picture), the plugin [`gvimfullscreen_win32`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2596) is highly recommended.

The plugin allows easier access to a full-screen mode and distraction-free environment.
You can also add `:set go=` to gain more space. 
Here is a screenshot (Gvim7.4 on Windows 8.1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu (16.04)

Better let the window-manager do this task, at least in **Ubuntu**, it will fullscreen `gvim` instead of maximizing window, giving you more space. Of course this solution is platform dependent and not cross-platform, but it is a much better option for **Ubuntu**. You can even set `gvim` to open on a specific **viewport**.

Compiz Config Settings Manager -> Place Windows -> Fixed Window Placement -> Windows with fixed placement mode -> new

```
 Windows class=Gvim
 Mode    Maximize
```

If you don't have Compiz Config Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

You already have the `gvim.lnk` at least in `Start Menu` – just change the property "Window size" ('*Start window size*', '*Window*', etc. Depends on locale settings and Windows version) to "Maximized".

For example, to start ***gVim*** from ***Powershell*** put this to your `$PROFILE` file:

```
Set-Alias gvim -Value "<Path to>\gVim.lnk"
```

**Note:** don't forget to correct the path to *`.lnk`*!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do this in your `$HOME/.vimrc` to achieve what you want:

```
if has("gui_running")
     set fuoptions=maxvert,maxhorz
     au GUIEnter * set fullscreen
 endif
```

You can confirm where the fullscreen is being applied like so:

```
:verbose set nofullscreen?
 fullscreen
       Last set from ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
```

Comment: Looks like this only work for MacVim.